# set invalid invalid form control in angular2

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Is it possible to set as invalid form control in angular2? (used form builder)

> eg. i have form-> exampleFrom  & field-> exampleControl

I have tried this, not succeed :

```
this.exampleFrom.controls['exampleControl'].invalid
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
let control = this.exampleFrom.controls['exampleControl'];
control.setErrors({backend: {someProp: "Backend message"}});
let message = control.errors['backend'].someProp;
```

Comment: Thanks dear. and if i want print that message on page. how i can ?

Comment: is it possible to set empty formcontrol ?

Comment: "empty" means without anything typed in yet? Yes you can, angular's `required` validator does that

Comment: How to set invalid property ?? like ex:: for touch I use markAsTouched()

Answer (score 2):

try this code for print message

```
 <div style='color:red' *ngIf="!exampleFrom.exampleControl.valid">
                        //set here your custom message
          </div>
```